# How to Scaffold database with the data inside it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using this code currently to scaffold a database.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost; Database=db; User Id=root; Password=;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore  --project ../Test.Api/ -c myContext -o Migrations
```

It works without a problem, but it only gives me the Tables, is there a way to also get the data inside the tables converted to EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to also get the data inside the tables converted to EF?

Not with EF. You would need to query the tables and save the data to JSON or somesuch.